# Is there any html template engine can be used both with ruby and php?

Tags: php, html, ruby, templates

there are two teams in my department, one use PHP while another use Ruby.

We want to share html template between two teams.

Is there any solutions for this requirement?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could try [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) Logic-less template